# I'm confused about CDiagramEngDoc *pDoc = (CDiagramEngDoc*)pChild->GetActiveDocument();

Tags: c++

How do you explain this? I am confused about how the first () got their and what it means.

```
CDiagramEngDoc *pDoc = (CDiagramEngDoc*)pChild->GetActiveDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to cast the pointer (likely to a derived type). It would be more usual in C++ to use `static_cast<CDiagramEngDoc*>(...)` here.

It's similar to if you were write `(float) 3` to convert `3` to `float`.